# Configuring comment form in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms

I've inherited a static website, with a typical contact form on the main page which takes a name, email, phone and message and should send an email to a set email address on submit. The JS and Slim partial below were given to me. I'm now trying to hook up to Rails using ActionMailer, but I'm doing something wrong with the form params and/or building of the email object. I'm not looking to store it in the database (tried with and without a model).

**Routes:**
`resources :contacts, only: [:new, :create]`

**_contact_form.slim**

(all I've changed is the `action` value)

```
form#contactform.form-horizontal action="/contacts" method="post" name="contactform" role="form"
        /! Field 1
        .row
          .col-md-6
            h3 name:
            .input-text.form-group.left-field
              input.input-name.form-control name="contact_name" type="text" /
          .col-md-6
            h3 Phone:
            .input-text.form-group
              input.input-name.form-control name="contact_phone" type="text" /
        /! Field 2
        h3 Email:
        .input-email.form-group
          input.input-email.form-control name="contact_email" type="email" /
        /! Field 3
        h3 Message:
        .textarea-message.form-group
          textarea.textarea-message.form-control name="contact_message" rows="7"
        /! Button
        button.btn.btn-default type="submit"
          | Submit
          i.flaticon-arrow209
```

**Javascript:**

(I've set the `url` and added the `beforeSend`)

```
  /* --------------------------------------------
Contact Form
-------------------------------------------- */
$(function($) {
    $('#contactform').bootstrapValidator({
        message: '',
        feedbackIcons: {
            valid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok',
            invalid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove',
            validating: 'glyphicon glyphicon-refresh'
        },
        fields: {
            contact_name: {
                validators: {
                    notEmpty: {
                        message: ''
                    }
                }
            },
            contact_email: {
                validators: {
                    notEmpty: {
                        message: ''
                    },
                    emailAddress: {
                        message: ''
                    }
                }
            },
            contact_message: {
                validators: {
                    notEmpty: {
                        message: ''
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        submitHandler: function(validator, form, submitButton) {
            $('.contact-form').addClass('ajax-loader');
            var data = $('#contactform').serialize();
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/contacts",
                beforeSend: function(xhr) {xhr.setRequestHeader('X-CSRF-Token', $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content'))},
                data: $('#contactform').serialize(),
                success: function(msg) {
                    $('.contact-form').removeClass('ajax-loader');
                    $('.form-message').html(msg);
                    $('.form-message').show();
                    submitButton.removeAttr("disabled");
                    resetForm($('#contactform'));
                },
                error: function(msg) {
                    $('.contact-form').removeClass('ajax-loader');
                    $('.form-message').html(msg);
                    $('.form-message').show();
                    submitButton.removeAttr("disabled");
                    resetForm($('#contactform'));
                }
            });
            return false;
        },
    });
    function resetForm($form) {
        $form.find('input:text, input:password, input, input:file, select, textarea').val('');
        $form.find('input:radio, input:checkbox').removeAttr('checked').removeAttr('selected');
    }
});
```

**contact.rb**

```
class Contact

  include ActiveModel::Model
  include ActiveModel::Conversion
  include ActiveModel::Validations

  attr_accessor :contact_name, :contact_phone, :contact_email, :contact_message

  validates :contact_name, :contact_email, :contact_message, presence: true

end
```

**contacts_controller.rb:**

```
class ContactsController < ApplicationController

  def create
    @contact = Contact.new(contact_params)

    if @contact.valid?
      ContactMailer.contact_email(@contact).deliver
      redirect_to new_contact_path, notice: "Thank you for your message."
    else
      flash[:alert] = "An error occurred while delivering this message."
      render :new
    end
  end

private

  def contact_params
    params.require(:contact).permit(:contact_name, :contact_phone, :contact_email, :contact_message)
  end

end
```

**contact_mailer.rb**

```
class ContactMailer < ActionMailer::Base

  default to: "me@myemailaddress.com"

  def contact_email(contact)
    @contact = contact

    mail(from: email: @contact.contact_email, body: @contact.contact_message)
  end

end
```

**contact_email.text.slim**

```
| New contact

= @contact.contact_name 
= @contact.contact_email 
| wrote:

= @contact.contact_message
```

**Current output from Rails Server**
[image: Rails Server]

I'm currently getting a syntax error in `contact_mailer.rb` on the `@contact` object, but prior to that the Rails server logs were telling me that the `Contact` object was uninitialized. I've tried including the `form_for`/`form_tag` Rails helpers but this hasn't seemed to help. I've also added an index action for the contact to the `HomeController` having read this suggestion elsewhere.

I can keep playing 'change the error message' but I imagine I'm getting something fundamental wrong (still a Rails newbie) so would really appreciate any pointers. I've read through the ActionMailer docs and everything else I can find.

Comment: Issue has nothing to do directly with javascript. Am removing that tag

Answer (score 0):

You need to have .deliver after your contact_mailer.rb call don't you?

Also, in your contact.rb try adding

```
after_create :send_email

private 
def send_email
    ContactMailer.contact_email(self).deliver
end
```

Comment: All the examples I could find had the deliver (or `deliver_now`) chained to the contact_mailer call. Also, `after_create` isn't recognised, I think because I'm not inheriting from ActiveRecord::Base (as not looking to store the form data in the db).